# How to change my camera position in bottom of layout

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin, maps

When I animate the camera with google maps function, my app is zooming in map and screen this into center of my layout. I want to show this bottom of my layout.

Here is my code.

```
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(latLng1)
                    .zoom(24f)
                    .bearing(-30)
                    .tilt(75)
                    .build();
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

bearing is not working.

Comment: Take a look at [Map padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=mdr-gdl#map_padding) and answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48194962/6950238) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58563200/6950238).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Google Maps Platform [Camera and View documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views):

> Target (location)
> The camera target is the location of the **center** of the map, specified as latitude and longitude co-ordinates.

You have to adjust your `target` latitude and longitude to get the camera to focus your desired location to the bottom of the screen.